# Add a line counter to lines matching a pattern

Tags: linux

I need to prepend a line counter to lines matching specific patterns in a file, while still outputting the lines that do not match this pattern.

For example, if my file looks like this:

```
aaa 123
bbb 456
aaa 666
ccc 777
bbb 999
```

and the patterns I want to count are 'aaa' and 'ccc', I'd like to get the following output:

```
1:aaa 123
bbb 456
2:aaa 666
3:ccc 777
bbb 999
```

Preferably I'm looking for a Linux one-liner. Shell or tool doesn't matter as long it's installed by default in most distros.

Comment: bash? perl? python? What have you tried? In current form the question's gonna get closed.

Comment: thanks - I clarified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{if ($1=="aaa" || $1=="ccc") {a++; $0=a":"$0}} {print}' file
1: aaa 123
bbb 456
2: aaa 666
3: ccc 777
bbb 999
```

#### Explanation

Loop through lines checking whether first field is `aaa` or `ccc`. If so, append the line (`$0`) with the variable `a` and auto increment it. Finally, print the line in all cases: if the pattern was matched will have `a` in the beginning, otherways just the original line.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code. The following approach is in perl

```
open FH,"<abc.txt";

$incremental_val = 1;

while(my $line = <FH>){
  chomp($line);

  if($line =~ m/^aaa / || $line =~ m/^ccc /){
    print "$incremental_val : $line\n";
    $incremental_val++;
    next;
  }
  print "$line\n";
}

close FH;
```

The output will be as follows.

```
1 : aaa 123
bbb 456
2 : aaa 666
3 : ccc 777
bbb 999
```